# Is careers gamified for employers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, employers

Recently I've been contacted by a few employers and I've noticed a pattern:

- We notice you live and work in X are you thinking of potentially moving to Y? We're based in Y
- Can you please send me a copy of your resume?

What frustrates me about these questions is that it is answered right there in my Careers profile, by which an employer found me. I've listed all the areas I'm willing to relocate to, and I use the Careers PDF resume as my primary resume with a few small tweaks.

So to my questions:

- Just to be sure; employers can see where we say we want to move to right?
- Can employers see a "download PDF resume" or equivalent link, or do they just see the profile on the webpage?
- Can we think about gamification for employers?

Allow me to expand on the last question. I love Careers because it allows me to place relevant information to my profession in a place employers can easily browse. They can hopefully see how I think and reason, especially when I'm stuck and go to Stack Overflow for help. It felt to me that it would remove the need for some of the awkward get to know you mandatory questions that you would ask on a first date, but instead allow you to get right to the part where you could focus on if you were a good match.

When an employer asks those questions, they're easily answered in a few lines, but it feels like a missed opportunity on the entire process.

I'm thinking what if employers were offered a benefit of some sort for asking the right to use Careers to its fullest extent? What if we could rate employers based on our interactions with them (did we feel like they viewed our full profile? did they ask questions that were on our profile) and offer some benefit that makes an employer more attractive to job seekers? Similar to the [Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) rating, maybe we can get a Careers usability rating from people who have come into contact with a company?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Employers do see your relocation preference in the top level of your profile, and have search filters specifically for relocation preferences.

There are two things currently in the pipeline that will help your issue:

1. Employers will be able to easily print your profile directly from a search result or from the applicant tracking system.
2. Employers will be able to download your profile in PDF format similarly to the way candidates can download their own now. This is not available for employers at this time.

As for gamification, I don't have a definitive answer for you on this yet.  Currently the best way for us to ensure quality messages from employers is for you to point out poor messages or bad actors to us on Meta, and we'll follow up with these companies.  Usually they are responsive and will adjust their messaging. It's in their best interest to convert  messages into interviews and sometimes just need to be told what doesn't work.

Comment: Like this one I received today? : "George,
I am the CEO of a small IT Services Company, A4 Solutions, and I have a position open in Arlington, VA for a C# .NET /SQL Programmer. Please let me know if you are interested and I will send you more information."

Comment: It's definitely short and not informative on what the actual job entails. He's basically meeting the bare minimum of identifying himself, company name, skills required.  We will encourage better descriptions in this case.

Comment: I don't currently see the ability to just have an employer be sent my Resume -- has #2 been implemented yet?